# Image Capture Fails on IPhone, no session data is displayable

Tags: php, iphone, session, variables, mobile

I currently use the following code as an image captcha.

```
<?php
session_start();    
$alphanum = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
// generate the verication code 
$rand = substr(str_shuffle($alphanum), 0, 5);
// choose one of four background images
$bgNum = rand(1, 4);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("background$bgNum.jpg");
$textColor = imagecolorallocate ($image, 0, 0, 0);
// create the hash for the random number and put it in the session
$_SESSION['image_random_value'] = md5($rand);
// write the random number
imagestring ($image, 15, 50, 10, $rand, $textColor);    
// Date in the past
header("Expires: Mon, 23 January 2009 01:00:00 GMT");
// always modified
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
// HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
// HTTP/1.0
header("Pragma: no-cache");
// send the content type header so the image is displayed properly
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
// send the image to the browser
imagejpeg($image);
// destroy the image to free up the memory
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

I then use the following to validate the captch code in the submit of the form...

```
if (md5(addslashes($_POST['antispam'])) != $_SESSION['image_random_value']) {
```

Ive been using this for years and it works perfect in browsers, however ive just realised it doesnt work on Iphones.

Using echo $_SESSION['image_random_value']; returns the session value in the browser but on the iphone it returns an empty variable?

Ive tired changing the expiration date, and commenting out some of the parameters ref cache control. But none of this works. 
For info also i do have cookies enabled on my iphone.

Any tips or pointers to what i have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for those with a similar issue it turned out i was pulling the script direct from the URL which of course was causing issues with setting a session. Hope that helps somebody.